# Complexity analysis exercise

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, quicksort, pseudocode

```
mcSort(A,l,r)  
  if r-l+1<4   
      then QuickSort(A,l,r)  
      else mcSort(A,l,r-3)  
           mcSort(A,l+3,r)
```

the exercise asks me to analize the complexity of the above algorithm.
My idea is that

```
T(n)=2T(n-3)+θ(1)
```

after k iterations we have:

```
T(n)=2^k * T(n-3k)+θ(1)*k
```

so when 3k=n thus k=n/3 we have

```
= 2^(n/3) * θ(1) + θ(n) = θ(2^(n/3))
```

Is that correct and precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after k iterations we have:
>
> ```
> T(n)=2^k * T(n-3k)+θ(1)*k
> ```

Not quite correct, since after each unroll the added multiple of `θ(1)` doubles:

[image]

Where we have used the standard formula for summing geometric series. Note that the trailing term is not `k` but `2^k`. Your stopping condition `n = 3k` is correct though, so:

[image]

Therefore your final result was correct, even though one of the reasoning steps was wrong.